# Vuex name function with namespaced in getters

Tags: vue.js, ecmascript-6, vuex

Hi I need create function which have payload.
In Vuex I created:

```
const getters = {
  [GettersTeam.GET_TEST](state) {
    return state.teams;
  },
  [GettersTeam.GET_TEAM]: state => id => {
    console.log("Run function!");
    console.log(id);
    return state.teams;
  },
};
```

Next I using this function in component:

```
mounted() {
    this.GET_TEAM(1);
},
methods: {
    ...mapGetters('TeamModule', [GettersTeam.GET_TEAM]),
},
```

Function `this.GET_TEAM(1)` nothing return. I thing the problem is with the name function `[GettersTeam.GET_TEAM]`, but I don't know how I can named function with namespaced. Function `this.GET_TEST()` work correctly.

**EDIT:**

I moved function from `methods` to `computed`.

```
computed: {
    ...mapGetters('TeamModule', {
        teamList: [GettersTeam.GET_TEAM],
    }),
},

<template>
    <div>
        teamList: {{ teamList }}
    </div>
</template>
```

But when I try using `teamList` in template Vue returned me this:

> teamList: function (id) { console.log(id); return state.teams; }

Comment: Is `GettersTeam.GET_TEAM` a string? Shouldn't it just be `mapGetters('TeamModule', GettersTeam.GET_TEAM)` (i.e. without the `[` and `]`)?

Comment: @DelenaMalan No, If You remove `[]` vuex return error: mapper parameter must be either an Array or an Object

Comment: Oh right. How about just `mapGetters([GettersTeam.GET_TEAM])` if `GettersTeam.GET_TEAM` already includes the namespace? Also how come `this.GET_TEST()` works if you don't include it in your `mapGetters`? Should also be `this[GettersTeam.GET_TEAM](1)` I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put `mapGetters` in your `computed` section, not `methods`:

```js
computed: {
    ...mapGetters('TeamModule', [GettersTeam.GET_TEAM]),
},
```

https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html#the-mapgetters-helper

That may seem slightly counter-intuitive given you're invoking it as a method but from the component's perspective it's still just a property. It just so happens that the property returns a function.

**Update:**

Based on the new question...

In your template you've got `{{ teamList }}`. That will be grabbing the value of the property `this.teamList`.

The property `this.teamList` is a computed property, so Vue will call the defining function behind the scenes. That defining function is created by `mapGetters` but it effectively just calls the store getter, passing it the relevant `state` object.

You've defined the getter like this:

```js
[GettersTeam.GET_TEAM]: state => id => {
```

Ignore the bit in the brackets, that isn't important here. The key bit is the `state => id => {` part. There are two functions here, one being returned by the other.

Effectively it is equivalent to this:

```js
[GettersTeam.GET_TEAM] (state) {
  return function (id) {
    console.log("Run function!");
    console.log(id);
    return state.teams;
  }
}
```

So when you access the computed property you're just going to be invoking that outer function. It'll return the inner function, which is what you're seeing your template.

To get the value returned by the inner function you'd need to invoke it. e.g.:

```
{{ teamList(1) }}
```

I would also note that your current implementation of the getter just ignores the `id`. It isn't clear exactly what you're trying to do but I assume you're intending to implement a search based on the `id` to find a particular entry within `state.teams`.

Answer (score 1):

Made a [Codepen](https://codepen.io/asdasgqq/pen/QWbraeP?editors=1010) for you.

Your `mapGetters` call should be `mapGetters([GettersTeam.GET_TEAM])` and your `this.GET_TEAM(1);` call should be `this[GettersTeam.GET_TEAM](1);` instead.